# How to configure logging to all scripts in the prject?

Tags: python, logging, package

I have put the following in my `config.py`:

```
import time
import logging
#logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)
logFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}.log".format(time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')))
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

and then I am doing

```
from config import *
```

in all of my scripts and imported files.

Unfortunately, this causes multiple log files created.

How to fix this? I wan't centralized `config.py` with logging configured both to console and file.

Comment: You can manually log them to a txt file using `with open('log.txt','a') as f:
f.write(logging part)` and do this for all the scripts with the same log.txt file.
And for console, you can use print statements.

Comment: I would like to print timestamp, with print it will require repetitive coding.

Comment: @Dims make it a function?

Comment: you can use datetime.datetime.now() as one of the parameters in the print. So, since you have to print the log anyway, you can print it with the timestamp.

Comment: How does the overall application look like? Is there kind of a "main" file that runs all modules? Or put differently: is this one application consisting of different parts (scripts), or are these (besides logging) independent scripts that run independently?

Comment: @TwUxTLi51Nus I'm pretty sure he's using independent scripts as in the other case, this question wouldn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1: Independent Scripts / Programs**

In case we are talking about multiple, independent scripts, that should have logging set up in the same way: I would say, each independent application should have its own log. If you definitively do not want this, you would have to

- make sure that all applications have the same log file name (e.g. create a function in config.py, with a parameter "timestamp", which is provided by your script(s)
- specify the `append` [filemode for the fileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)
- make sure that `config.py` is not called twice somewhere, as you would add the log handlers twice, which would result in each log message being printed twice.

**Case 2: One big application consisting of modules**

In case we are talking about one big application, consisting of modules, you could adopt a structure like the following:

config.py:

```
def set_up_logging():
    # your logging setup code
```

module example (some_module.py):

```
import logging

def some_function():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    [...]

    logger.info('sample log')

    [...]
```

main example (main.py)

```
import logging
from config import set_up_logging
from some_module import some_function

def main():
    set_up_logging()

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('Executing some function')

    some_function()

    logger.info('Finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Explanation:

- With the call to `set_up_logging()` in main() you configure your applications root logger
- each module is called from main(), and get its logger via `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. As the modules logger are in the hierarchy below the root logger, those loggings get "propagated up" to the root logger and handled by the handlers of the root logger.

For more information see [Pythons logging module doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) and/or the [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook)